# Multiple Files in Xcode

Tags: c, xcode

when I try to run a file which is with my other files in Xcode project, I get the failed message. If I delete files and keep only one then it works. What should I do to keep all my files in one project ?

Comment: You will need to provide more information than that. What kind of error do you get? Xcode normally allows you to have as many files in your project as you need. Any chance that you have your main function defined in more than one file? That would cause an error if all files belong under the same target.

Comment: @Roman Kutlak Thanks for your answer, I get the message "Build Failed".
I have for example ten different files which I want to run under the same project.

Comment: "Build Failed" is a message you get from the IDE. Look into the console for the reason why it failed. Look under "View/Navigators/Show Report Navigator" then select the build and you should see more verbose output in the main pane.

Comment: @Roman Kutlak OK, let's forget the build failed. I'd like to have 2 files.c in the same project and take different output for each (they are different programs). Is this possible ? I ask this because now I have 2 files.c but I get the same output from the first file (I can't take the output from the other).

Comment: Sure. If you have two programs (two files with main() in them) you can create two targets - one per file. Try to create an empty project and then add two targets for Command Line tool. Each of the targets will have its own main.c file with the main function. Depending on which target you pick it will compile only that one file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create an empty project. Then create two targets -- assuming you are using C, File/New/Target and under OS X/Application select Command Line Tool.

Each target has its own set of files, which are compiled independently.

[image: A project with two targets]

Comment: Whatever I pick it only runs the first file, not the one I pick. What I missed here ?

Comment: You can choose which target to compile by selecting it in the top left corner next to the play/stop buttons.

Comment: Thank you, it works ! As I can see the first program (called 'Hello world') it appears as Myprograms, next to stop button. Is there a way to rename it there ?

Comment: You would have to rename the target. When you select the project name in the browser on the left, it will list all targets. You should be able to rename them as you wish.